# Error running Android emulator from Titanium Studio

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Basically trying to get the [default sample project](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink) (which is [linked to here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Example+Applications)) to run in the Android simulator.

(I'm on Windows XP-SP3, see the "Diagnostics Log" output in the question's footer for more config info, if you have any questions about configs let me know.)

Here's what I've done so far:

- Installed the current version of Titanium Mobile SDK Version: 2.0.1
- Installed the Java SDK "jdk-6u31-windows-i586.exe"
- Installed the Android SDK Manager r18, then the following packages: Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform Tools, Android 2.2 API-8 SDK Platform, Android 2.2 API-8 Google APIs
- Downloaded the zip of Kitchen Sink on GitHub, unzipped the file, changed the file name to KitchenSink, copied the file to the Titanium project directory under "My Documents", then via the file tab executed an import on that directory to the "Project Explorer" tab in Titanium Studio.
- Then I right clicked on the KitchenSink project in "Project Explorer" tab in Titanium Studio, and selected "Run As...", then "Android Emulator"
- Oddly, doing this returns different results (meaning I run it, restart, etc.), which include:

  - **ERROR-MSG:** Problem Occurred 'Launching Titanium Android Emulator - KitchenSink' has encountered a problem. Session initialization failed. Connection refused: connect.
  - Another times, I've gotten a message in this form "[INFO] [2012-04-24 17:03:33,140] Serving up files for com.test.test at 0.0.0.0:1133 from C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test" which appears to as the app was deploy to a server under an static-IP, but no emulator ever appears; which to me seemed like a bad IP address, though might be wrong.

**What do I need to do to get KitchenSink to run in the Android Simulator? Is there a way to just run the Android Simulator to confirm it's working on it's own?**

---

Here's the full output from the "Diagnostics Log" under the help tab:

- **Host OS:** Windows XP
- **OS Arch:** x86
- **JRE Version:** 1.6.0_24
- **JRE Vendor:** Sun Microsystems Inc.
- **JRE Home:** C:\Program Files\Appcelerator\Titanium Studio\jre
- **Install Directory:** file:/C:/Program Files/Appcelerator/Titanium Studio/
- **Version:** 2.0.1.201204132053
- **VM Arguments:** -Xms40m -Xmx1024m -Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow -Declipse.log.size.max=10000
  -Declipse.log.backup.max=5
  -Djava.awt.headless=true
  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
  -Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files\Appcelerator\Titanium Studio\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
- **Workspace Directory:** file:/C:/Documents and Settings/user/My Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/
- **Language:** en_US
- **Titanium Desktop SDK Version:** 1.1.0
- **Titanium Desktop SDK Location:** C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Titanium\sdk\win32\1.1.0
- **Titanium Mobile SDK Version:** 2.0.1
- **Mobile SDK Modules API Version:** 2
- **Mobile SDK Timestamp:** 04/12/12 16:33
- **Mobile SDK Build Number:** 999c68a
- **Titanium Mobile SDK Location:** C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.0.1.GA2

---

Per the suggestion below, I created a new mobile project targeting Android, and then ran the project using the "Run As..." Android emulator option. The system returned this messages: "[INFO] [2012-04-24 17:03:33,140] Serving up files for com.test.test at 0.0.0.0:1133 from C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test"

**build.log Output:**
C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test\build.log

```
Logfile initialized
[INFO] logfile = C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test\build.log
[DEBUG] C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.0.1.GA2\android\builder.py simulator test C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test com.test.test 1 HVGA
[INFO] logfile = C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test\build.log
[DEBUG] C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.0.1.GA2\android\builder.py emulator test C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test com.test.test 1 HVGA
[ERROR] Error locating JDK: set $JAVA_HOME or put javac and jarsigner on your $PATH
[ERROR] Error locating JDK: set $JAVA_HOME or put javac and jarsigner on your $PATH
```

**Windows commands (java,javac,jarsigner) all return valid responses, which appears to conflict with the build.log file saying the JDK is not in the file path. The path is currently set as:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin"
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
Logfile initialized
[INFO] logfile = C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test3\build.log
[DEBUG] C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.0.1.GA2\android\builder.py simulator test3 C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test3 com.tester.test3 1 HVGA
[INFO] Building test3 for Android ... one moment
[ERROR] JDK version 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file. detected, but 1.6 is required
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one to see is ur config ok, create a new project and run that, it should have a default app.js page with 2 tabs on it, if that doesn't work its a config issue

if that fails try following the steps here for setting up titanium:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio-section-30086257_SettingupTitaniumStudio-SoftwareLocations

Or here for setting up environment variables:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables

Comment: Makes sense, possible I've even done that, but in doing that, I ran across the other message I've seen before **"[INFO] [2012-04-24 17:03:33,140] Serving up files for com.test.test at 0.0.0.0:1133 from C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\test"** -- and no emulator ever appears.

Comment: +1 Simon McLoughlin: All I need to do is install Ti-Studio, Java-SDK-1.6 (one listed above), and Installed the Android SDK Manager r18, then the following packages: Android SDK Tools, Android SDK Platform Tools, Android 2.2 API-8 SDK Platform, Android 2.2 API-8 Google APIs (and link to the correct DIR in the Ti-Studio prefs for Android without error) -- then create a new mobile project, right click on it, and select "Run As..." click "Android Emulator"; after that I should get the message above, "[INFO]..." and an Android Emulator should pop-up in a pop-window, right, or no? Thanks!

Comment: yes as far i no that should be it. you can create a run configuration to specify what emulator runs / sdk / log level on the console etc, not sure if this is necessary or not, maybe give that a go also ? (drop down arrow beside the run button up top)

Comment: So, think I've found the issue, though still have no idea what needs to be done. This file "C:/Documents and Settings/user/Application Data/Titanium/mobilesdk/win32/2.0.1.GA2/android/builder.py" has the error message I listed in the update to the question, which is in **def set_java_commands(self):** appears JAVA_HOME really is not set correctly... any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: did u set your JAVA_HOME var ? check this out : http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128820/error-locating-jdk-set-javahome-or-put-javac-and-jarsigner-on-your-path-

Comment: I haven't seen that page, but I had been looking at [this one](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/21091/error-error-locating-jdk-set-javahome-or-put-javac-and-jarsigner-on-your-path). So far, I've found that QnA site hard to use, and full of bad answers; case in point, the answer that suggest editing the python on the page I just linked to.

Comment: That said, it appears I got the Android emulator to work by following the directions on [this page](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows), but replaced "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6" with "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31"; oddly, when I restarted, created a new Android project, and ran it, it through a new error, but the KitchenSink app ran... (no idea why, since I had removed it Ti-Studio project directory in "My Docs", too funny.) Not sure if the new error message is related, but I'll post it to the body of the question.

Comment: Well, no idea why, but the Ti-Studio kept building, the rebuilding the default Android app, with just one request, though oddly, when I had this happen a few times, I decided to click the red "terminate" button from the console for Ti-Studio... and got a emulator that looks [like this](http://www.hlplus.jp/android/avd/setting/image/avd010.png); before, it was either "Android_" with the underscore blinking, or just black. That said, my understanding from you was that if I select the "tabbed" template for the default new Android project, I should see a tabbed app when the app open, right?

Comment: yes that error your getting is a java issue. javac is the command to compile a java file, so titanium is complaining that it can't find your java set up. here is a detailed install guide: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio-section-30086257_SettingupTitaniumStudio-SoftwareLocations
  and here is one on environment variables: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables

Comment: Yes, you're correct (the [same info is in the wiki](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Configuring+Environment+Variables#ConfiguringEnvironmentVariables-WindowsSoftwareLocations) to, not sure what the diff is btwn the docs and wiki) - please update your answer, and thank you for all of your help, I'm going to upvote all of your comments, and I'll update your answer as the answer after the links are present in the body of your answer so ppl don't have to read 9 comments to find the answer. Again, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your system environment variables are not set correctly.
Try to set them like this:

```
android_sdk : C:\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31
PATH : %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%android_sdk%;C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Android\android-sdk\tools
```

In Control Panel -> System -> (On Windows 7: Advanced system settings ->) Advanced tab -> Environment Variables
Create 2 new variables with the names "android_sdk" and "JAVA_HOME" with the right values.
After that change your system PATH variable and add the line I've pasted here.
(Also try not to use spaces in your android_sdk path, just as a precaution)

Comment: I agree the "android_sdk" is in the screengrab in both docs linked to above, but so far the android-sdk builds appear okay without the env-var-name "android_sdk". Any idea what it's for? Thanks!

Comment: PS- Huge thanks for joining the [proposal to create a SE just for Appcelerator](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40242/appcelerator). If possible, please post five sample questions, and upvote all the existing sample questions that are not off-topic. Reason being we need 40 questions each with 10-upvotes each to move onto the next phase in launching the site as a public beta... :-) ...again thanks, and cheers!!