# Appcelerator Titanium does not run with sample application KitchenSink

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I've installed Appcelerator Titanium Studio on a PC and I was not able to run the android simulator on it, so I was saying to myself "it should work on Mac at least"... and I installed a new Mac with Titanium on it, downloaded the SDK, then I imported the Kitchen Sink example and configured the run configuration with the default settings... and I'm getting exactly the same problem which is an infinite loop with the 'audio_flinged died' problem! So the best I can do is to view the Android simulator with the black window and "Android..." written on it.

What can I do to finally launch that example that is supposed to run? The best I did with my Windows 7 setup was to get the screen of an android cellphone WITHOUT any app on it (default apps), so it's pretty unuseful.

I'd really like to see what Titanium is capable to do.
The Mac ends (after a few mins) with "Launching New_configuration" has encountered a problem. Session initialization failed. "Session initialization failed Failed to get version"
The problem of the infinite loop with "AudioFlinger" still persist in the two cases (PC/Mac).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 @Myka Eyl: Thanks for [Appcelerator.SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40242/appcmentor?referrer=4KLbbThHxCWfDpFmz1HCvA2) - any luck getting the android simulator to run? One suggestion I would have is that you don't run KitchenSink first, but just create an new mobile project, and make sure Android is selected as a deployment option. As for OSX, which version are you running it on? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I helped someone with a similar question. He was getting a error which you don't seem to be but my answer walked him through checking the configuration was ok etc.

might help you:

[Error running Android emulator from Titanium Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300661/error-running-android-emulator-from-titanium-studio/10305464)